# Idenitity UserManager ConfirmEmailAsync error

Tags: identity, email-confirmation

Visual Studio 2013 / MVC 5 / Identity 2

Still a bit new to using built in email confirmation...

testing under localhost - no errors

in production - I am getting an error when user tries to confirm email

```
var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
```

On the server, result.Succeeded is always false.

Where should I look to see an error? It's on GoDaddy server so I don't have complete access...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you create "`UserTokenProvider`" for the user manager?

I think this is something to do with that, because you need to make sure that,

```
UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
```

and

```
UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
```

both uses the same `DataProtectorTokenProvider`.

```
manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
```

Make sure you create this during the startup which will help you to keep one per owin request.

Answer (score 0):

I think right answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37423990/5320046) - using mashineKey in your web.config make you happening.